The integral basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$
Question
$\quad$ Let $p$ is an odd prime number, denote $\zeta=\mathrm{e}^\frac{2\pi \mathrm{i}}{p}$, $s = \frac{p-1}{2}$, $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$.
$\quad$ Proof that $\{\zeta^i+\zeta^{-i}|1\le i\le s\}$
is an integral basis of $K$.
My idea
$\quad$ I know that the problem is equivalent to the following:
$\quad$ Proof that integral domain of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta+\zeta^{-1}]$.
$\quad$ It's easy to know that $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta+\zeta^{-1}] \subseteq O_K$ because $\zeta^i+\zeta^{-i} \in O_K$ for every $1\le i\le s$. And $\{\zeta^i+\zeta^{-i}|1\le i\le \frac{p-1}{2}\}$
is a basis of K. So I only need to proof that $O_K \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[\zeta+\zeta^{-1}]$.
$\quad$ $\forall\ \alpha\in O_K$, so $\alpha=t_1(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})+t_2(\zeta^2+\zeta^{-2})+\cdots+t_s(\zeta^s+\zeta^{-s}),\ t_i\in \mathbb{Q}$. I want to proof that $t_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.
$\quad$ Denote $\sigma_i:K\mapsto\mathbb{C},\ \sigma(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})=\zeta^i+\zeta^{-i},\ 1\le i\le s$.
$\quad$ Acting all $\sigma_i$ to $\alpha$ and get a system of linear equations:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 \zeta+\zeta^{-1}      & \zeta^2+\zeta^{-2}     & \cdots & \zeta^s+\zeta^{-s} \\
 \zeta^{-2}+\zeta^{-2} & \zeta^4+\zeta^{-4}     & \cdots & \zeta^{2s}+\zeta^{-2s} \\
 \vdots                & \vdots                 & \ddots & \vdots \\
 \zeta^{-s}+\zeta^{-s} & \zeta^{2s}+\zeta^{-2s} & \cdots & \zeta^{s^2}+\zeta^{-s^2}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
t_1 \\
t_2 \\
\vdots \\
t_s
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_1({\alpha}) \\
\sigma_2(\alpha) \\
\vdots \\
\sigma_s(\alpha)
\end{pmatrix}$$
$\quad$ By Cramer's Rule: $t_i=\frac{\gamma_i}{\delta},\ 1\le i\le s$, where $\delta$ is the determinant of the coefficient matrix. $\gamma_i$ is the determinant of the matrix replaced by a constant vector.
$\quad$ Denote $d=\delta^2$, and I calculate that $d=p^l \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $l=\frac{p-3}{2}$.
$\quad$ And $dt_i=\delta\gamma_i$ is an algebraic integer. And because $d\in \mathbb{Z},\ t_i\in \mathbb{Q}$, I get that $dt_i\in \mathbb{Z}$, denoted as $m_i$. Therefore $t_i=\frac{m_i}{d}$, $\alpha=\frac{m_1}{d}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})+\frac{m_2}{d}(\zeta^2+\zeta^{-2})+\cdots+\frac{m_s}{d}(\zeta^s+\zeta^{-s})$. I need to proof that $d|m_i$.
$\quad$ Noticed that $d$ is a power of $p$. If $(m_1,m_2,\cdots,m_s)=mp^\lambda,\ (m,p)=1$. Let $m_i=p^\lambda m_i'$, and assuming that $d \nmid m_t$, but $d|m_i,\ 1 \le i \le t-1$. So it's equivalent to $p \nmid m_t'$, but $p|m_i',\ 1 \le i \le t-1$.
$\quad$ Therefore $p^{l-\lambda-1}\alpha-\frac{m_1'}{p}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})-\cdots-\frac{m_{t-1}'}{p}(\zeta^{t-1}+\zeta^{1-t})=\frac{m_t'}{p}(\zeta^t+\zeta^{-t})+\cdots+\frac{m_s'}{p}(\zeta^s+\zeta^{-s})$.
$\quad$ I know that the left side is an algebraic integer and should derive a contradiction that $p|m_t'$ actually, but I can't get the next step now.
$\quad$ The above steps were written by imitating the proof that Integral domain of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$. I'm sorry that I can't attach the original process of proof, because my reference book is not in English. And thank you for your help.

First, a priori you want to show that every element of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is of the form $\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-3}{2}} t_i (\zeta+\zeta^{-1})^i$ with $t_i\in\mathbb{Z}$, and not of the form $t_0+
\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-3}{2}} t_i (\zeta^i+\zeta^{-i})$. But it is indeed equivalent, after developping. The matrix of base change from the basis $((\zeta+\zeta^{-1})^i)$ to the basis $(\zeta^i+\zeta^{-i})$ is upper triangular, with integer coefficients and $1$s' on the diagonal, thus has an inverse with integer coefficients.
It is always hard to prove that an extension if monogenic. If you want to follow your idea without using more results, you may try to find a suitable element that has an interesting norm, and write things with this element.
But you may try to use that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)}=\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$.
Writing $x\in \mathcal{O}_K$ as $x=t_0+\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{p-3}{2}} t_i(\zeta^i +\zeta^{-i})$. Then you may write $x=\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-3}{2}} t_i\zeta^i + \sum_{i=p-\frac{p-3}{2}}^{p-2} t_{p-i}\zeta^i + t_1 \zeta^{p-1}= \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{p-3}{2}} (t_i-t_1)\zeta^i -t_1\zeta^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-t_1\zeta^{\frac{p+1}{2}} + \sum_{i=\frac{p+3}{2}}^{p-2} (t_{p-i}-t_1)\zeta^i$.
It is an element of $\mathcal{O}_K$, thus an element of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)}$, thus $t_1\in\mathbb{Z}$ and every $t_i-t_1$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$. Thus $t_i\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Yes. I skipped the process of equivalence of the two sets of basis, which was slightly less rigorous.
And I'm sure that the norms of these basis are not interesting enough. But it is also difficult to find a suitable element which has an interesting norm and I'm stuck at this step.
Thank you for your additions and help!
